# What's wrong with this computation of algebraic de Rham cohomology of a disjoint union?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, de-rham-cohomology

Let $R$ be a ring, $S = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

The algebraic de Rham cohomology is

$$H^i_{dR}(S/R) \cong
\begin{cases}
R & i=0 \\
0 & i>0
\end{cases}$$

Then I would expect of the disjoint union

$$H^i_{dR}(S\coprod S/R) \cong
\begin{cases}
R\oplus R & i=0 \\
0 & i>0
\end{cases}$$

however my calculations show

$$H^i_{dR}(S\coprod S/R) \cong?
\begin{cases}
R & i=0 \\
R & i=1
\end{cases}$$

Would you kindly identify the source of my stupidity?

Set $A := R[x]/(x(x-1))$, so that $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \mathrm{Spec}(R) \coprod \mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

There is a representation of each element
$$A\ni a = r_0 + r_1x$$
$$\Omega_{A/R} \ni \omega = (s_0 + s_1x)dx$$
for some $r_i,s_i \in R$

The de Rham complex is

$$A\xrightarrow{d}\Omega_{A/R}$$
$$r_0 + r_1x \mapsto (r_1 + 0x)dx$$

Then
$$\mathrm{ker}(d) = \{r_0 + 0x\} \subset A$$
$$\mathrm{im}(d) = \{(s_0 + 0x)dx\} \subset \Omega$$
$$\mathrm{coker}(d) \cong \{(0 + s_1x)dx\} \cong R$$

So it looks like both $H^0_{dR}, H^1_{dR}$ are isomorphic to $R$.
Is that what's supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the ring $A$, one has $x^2-x=0$. Thus inside $\Omega_{A/R}$ we know
$$0=d(x^2-x)=2xdx-dx=(2x-1)dx.$$
Since $2x-1$ is a unit in $R$ (to see this you can either use the Chinese remainder theorem or check explicity that in fact it is its own inverse), this implies $dx=0$. Thus $\Omega_{A/R}=A$ and $$d:A\to \Omega_{A/R}$$ is just the identity. This now yields the correct cohomology groups.

Comment: Ah yes, the relation in $\Omega$, of course. Thank you.